# Send TCP/UDP packets from the outside to a client behind a router

Tags: networking, multicast, packet, nat

I want to send packets to a client on a lan, say, the public address is:
15.15.15.15 and behind this, there are 3 machines:
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12

How would format my packet so that, if I were to send it to this IP address, it'll be received, well, atleast redirected to say, 192.168.0.10.

I know that there's 192.168.0.10, since it's one of my machines and I was wondering if I can build a notification system for something using no sockets whatsoever, but just a client listening for these. (Using scapy to parse packets)

So, for example: I send a packet from outside saying "Alert!" to 15.15.15.15 and 192.168.0.12 picks it up. Wrote this just to provide some insight!

Made this image to portray the process:
[image: How it works.]

Cheers.

Comment: You may want to have a look at NAT(PAT), this will solve your problem. Or you could do port-forwarding. All in all, you'll be better off asking this question on Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement a [UDP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching), but you need a public server with real IP address to do that.